# Logs on Parse-Server

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

With the logs that parse-server has, there is no way for someone to find out in the above situation, what the IP of the user is.

How can we workaround something like this?

---

Imagine this scenario

One friend got an issue with the Police.
Before some months the User A commented on a picture of User B some insults. And of course the admin banned the User A.

Although User B made a complaint to the Police about User A.

Yeah seriously. And the Police asked from the admin to give them the logs to see the IP of User A and find him. If the admin has no logs with the IP he will get charged for cover up !!!

Comment: check the docs for whatever host provider / PAAS is in use with parse-server

Answer (score 1):

You can see the IP address in the parse logs by looking for the header parameter x-forwarded-for (or perhaps another depending on which service provider hosts your parse server).  Here is a snapshop of my logs:

```
{"method":"GET","url":"/parse/classes/_User",..."x-forwarded-for":"13.***.***.***:PORT",...
```

Good luck.

Comment: will investigate tomorrow and i'll get back at you. Thanks although :D